# Are we posting the questions on Twitter?

Tags: feature-request

I am not there on twitter, but when I was going through my own question that I asked about 6 hrs ago, I looked for the edits, and saw this:

[image]

And then I followed the link:

[image]

Are we posting our questions to twitter? Sounds exciting! Is there any criteria to choose what question to post there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, each site has a Twitter feed which sends out the top posts from the site automatically. The Twitter feed grabs up to 8 “Hot” questions per day I believe, but I don’t know the exact criteria.